# bootstrap solr on tomcat with compositeID routing

Tags: solr, tomcat7

We are upgrading solr 4.0 to solr 4.3.1 on tomcat 7.

We would like to use the "compositeId" router. It seems that there are two ways to do that: 
       1. using collections API to create a new collection by passing "numShards"; 
       2. Passing "numShards" in bootstrap process.

For 1, we have a large amount of existing index data that we don't want to reindex. Hence, we can't create new collections.

SolrCloud wiki use examples of jetty where it is possible to pass "numShards" parameter. Is it possible to do it in tomcat?

This is currently what happens in solr 4.3.1 on tomcat 7. When doing the default bootstrap: solr read "solr.xml" to find all solr cores and bootstrap all of them. however, the hash range of a solr core shows "null" in : "clusterstate.json" in zookeeper and will result in using "implicit" router.

Thanks!

Comment: Please ask these type of questions on meta stack.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to set up collection with Solr running in Tomcat (ZooKeeper runs separately) you should use Collections API: i.e. you can specify number of shards (numShards) and other parameters when calling CREATE action.

With Solr 4.3.1 there's a nice option now that allows splitting existing shards. Please, check out SPLITSHARDS in Collections API.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud (some points about collections API are also there)